# Proving that $\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{{n \choose 2k}\cdot 3^{n-2k}}=2^{n-1}(2^n+1) $

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{{n \choose 2k}\cdot 3^{n-2k}}=2^{n-1}(2^n+1)\,.$$
Can somebody help me prove this identity?

Comment: It seems that this identity comes from some generating function.

Comment: Do you need a combinatorial proof or any?

Comment: **Hint.** The right-hand side is $$\frac{4^n+2^n}{2}=\frac{(3+1)^n+(3-1)^n}{2}\,.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2} = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $2\mid k$} \\
0 &\text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$
So
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{2k}3^{n-2k}
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{k}3^{n-k} \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{k}3^{n-k} 
+ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{k}3^{n-k} (-1)^k\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1+3)^n 
+ \frac{1}{2}(-1+3)^n\\
&= \frac{4^n+2^n}{2} \\
&= 2^{n-1}(2^n+1)
\end{align}

---

Here's an alternative proof that uses generating functions:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{2k}3^{n-2k} z^n
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} z^{2k} \sum_{n \ge 2k} \binom{n}{2k}(3z)^{n-2k} \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 0} z^{2k} \frac{1}{(1-3z)^{2k+1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-3z}\sum_{k \ge 0} \left(\frac{z}{1-3z}\right)^{2k} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-3z}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{z}{1-3z}\right)^2} \\
&= \frac{1-3z}{1-6z+8z^2} \\
&= \frac{1/2}{1-4z} + \frac{1/2}{1-2z} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 0} (4z)^n + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 0} (2z)^n \\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{4^n+2^n}{2} z^n
\end{align}
So
$$\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{2k}3^{n-2k} = \frac{4^n+2^n}{2}$$

Comment: thanks. you saved me